# Overlay in front of SwiftUI tab view

Tags: ios, swiftui, viewmodifier

I'm using SwiftUI's `TabView` and I want to add a custom `bottomSheet()` modifier which accepts a view and displays it like the standard `sheet()` modifier, but without occupying the entire screen.

**Current Behaviour**: I managed to create the custom modifier and show a sheet, but the sheet comes up behind the bottom tab bar (since it is displayed from within the `NavigationView`).

**Expected Behavior:** I'm looking for a way to cover the tab bar with the sheet in front.

[image]

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

Here's the custom modifier that I've created.

```
struct BottomSheet<SheetContent: View>: ViewModifier {
    
    let sheetContent: SheetContent
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> SheetContent) {
        self.sheetContent = content()
        _isPresented = isPresented
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content
            if isPresented {
                ZStack {
                    Color.black.opacity(0.1)
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        sheetContent
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(
                                Rectangle()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func bottomSheet<SheetContent: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> SheetContent) -> some View {
        self.modifier(BottomSheet(isPresented: isPresented, content: content))
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm using it.

```
struct ScheduleTab: View {
    
    @State private var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button("Open Sheet") {
                showSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Today")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .bottomSheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Text("Hello, World")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks you applied `bottomSheet` modifier to internal tab view, but should apply it to `TabView` itself to have it above.

Comment: @Asperi Yes that I'm aware of, but I was looking for a solution which can do it from within the tab. As a last resort, I will put it on the `TabView` and then have an enum to show different sheets for different tabs.

Comment: Does it have to be that small? With the new `adaptiveSheetController` you can [easily achieve a half modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700752/swiftui-half-modal/67994666#67994666) that show above it all. But it is only available iOS and macCatalyst 15+. You might be able to create it with your [custom size with a `UIViewController`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737884/changing-the-size-of-a-modal-view-controller)

Comment: @loremipsum That is a good solution, but as of now I'm targetting iOS 14+

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I have the same problem and couldn't solve it yet

Comment: @aliyasineser Not yet, but I ended up putting the `bottomSheet` modifier on the `TabView` block (i.e. parent view) and passing an enum `Binding` down to individual tabs. So, whenever the binding enum changes, I switch to a different bottom sheet in the parent view. Works well for now, but not the most elegant approach :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, until someone came up with a cleaner solution I would like to use yours. It was a valuable answer, appreciated.

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria Hey Hi, Can you please upload the solution that worked for you? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @Bella I already commented on the approach in one of my comments. One other idea I can think of is to use `PreferenceKey` in SwiftUI to pass which sheet to show from the child view to the parent view and have the custom sheet modifier on the parent `TabView`. The benefit to this approach is that you don't have the ugly `Binding`s everywhere and you can pass the data up to any parent of the child views. Maybe you can try it out with `PreferenceKey` and write an answer here :)